# Pylance getting "Expect expression" and "Zero-length tuple is not allowed in this context" for dict indexing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am attempting to get a value from a h5 dataset using h5py with the dict-like indexing. I tested the code and it works, but pylance shows me this error in vscode.

The error "Expect expression" and "Zero-length tuple is not allowed in this context" are marked by the red underline in the picture below.

`_artemis_file` here is the h5 file. And the code snippet below is in a method.

EDIT: the method `self.calc_points()` returns a list.

[image]

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and show code [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Please also read [mre] and try to show code that others can use to demonstrate the problem for themselves.

Comment: Can you provide code to reproduces the problem? This can help us solve your problem effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like it was an error with how I added the type hint for the `_artemis_file` instance variable above.

Comment: Hi Austin Benny, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)